# Getting an (Type any has no subscript members) error when parsing JSON with swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift3

When I run this code it throws an error at the block where I'm trying to get the weather id.

> type Any has no subscript members

I tried casting it as type `any` and changing `Anyobject` to `Any` but that does not seem to work

```
func getWeather(city: String) {

        // This is a pretty simple networking task, so the shared session will do.
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let weatherRequestURL = URL(string: "\(openWeatherMapBaseURL)?APPID=\(openWeatherMapAPIKey)&q=\(city)")!

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherRequestURL) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }else {

                do {
                    // Try to convert that data into a Swift dictionary
                    let weather = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
                        with: data!,
                    options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]                    // If we made it to this point, we've successfully converted the
                    // JSON-formatted weather data into a Swift dictionary.
                    // Let's print its contents to the debug console.
                    print("Date and time: \(weather["dt"]!)")
                    print("City: \(weather["name"]!)")

                    print("Longitude: \(weather["coord"]!["lon"]!!)")
                    print("Latitude: \(weather["coord"]!["lat"]!!)")

                    print("Weather ID: \(weather["weather"]![0]!["id"]!!)")
                    print("Weather main: \(weather["weather"]![0]!["main"]!!)")
                    print("Weather description: \(weather["weather"]![0]!["description"]!!)")
                    print("Weather icon ID: \(weather["weather"]![0]!["icon"]!!)")

                    print("Temperature: \(weather["main"]!["temp"]!!)")
                    print("Humidity: \(weather["main"]!["humidity"]!!)")
                    print("Pressure: \(weather["main"]!["pressure"]!!)")

                    print("Cloud cover: \(weather["clouds"]!["all"]!!)")

                    print("Wind direction: \(weather["wind"]!["deg"]!!) degrees")
                    print("Wind speed: \(weather["wind"]!["speed"]!!)")

                    print("Country: \(weather["sys"]!["country"]!!)")
                    print("Sunrise: \(weather["sys"]!["sunrise"]!!)")
                    print("Sunset: \(weather["sys"]!["sunset"]!!)")
                }
                catch let jsonError as NSError {
                    // An error occurred while trying to convert the data into a Swift dictionary.
                    print("JSON error description: \(jsonError.description)")
                }

            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Please [search on an error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+type+Any+has+no+subscript+members+json) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to Any or AnyObject cannot be subscripted. NSArrays and NSDictionaries can. You need to cast the Object to the right type and then subscript it. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

subscript is used when you like to access an inner element of a container.
You subscript an Array using **index** and dictionary using **key**.

Swift is a Static typing language meaning even though something *is* returning a dictionary *while* you told the compiler it's of type `Any` ...then the compiler would treat it as such (type Any and *not* type dictionary) and for such a type there is no ability to subscript. Once you get something from type `Any` **you have to downcast** it using `as` keyword.

```
let JSONItem as Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another casting before the last subscript use. What casting you need to use depends on the type you expect. For example if you expect
weather["weather"][0] to be a dictionary of type [String:AnyObject], change this line:

print("Weather ID: (weather["weather"]![0]!["id"]!!)")

To this line:

print("Weather ID: ((weather["weather"]![0]! as! [String:AnyObject])["id"]!)")